# golang net.Conn does not have Data available property

Tags: c#, go

I am new to go. I have been coding in `C#` but I need server as well. So I have written a server:

```
func ServeToClient(client net.Conn) {
for {
    fmt.Fprintln(client,"Serving you!")
    buffer:=make([]byte,1024)
    _, err :=bufio.NewReader(client).Read(buffer)
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        client.Close()
        fmt.Println("Disconnected duet to the error: ",err.Error())
        return
    }
    data := string(buffer)
    fmt.Println(data)
    command := data[0:2]
    i,err := strconv.Atoi(command)
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

But it sees the `data` as :

> {"id":"009","username":"Bungler"}??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

And I guess it is owing to excess of byte byte array(it is in 1024 length). Is there any property (like in `C# Socket.Availabe`) to create my byte array properly?

Comment: You should not ignore the *number of byte read*, i.e, first return value of `Read` method. In network communication, typically you must read the data chunk by chunk, then combine them to got the whole byte stream. If your data is in JSON format, use [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder), i.e. `decoder := json.NewDecoder(client)` then get the object by `decoder.Decode(&obj)`.

Comment: Yeap. I got you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [Read()](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) you're ignoring the number of bytes read into variable **buffer**, on this line:

`_, err := bufio.NewReader(client).Read(buffer)`

Just add a new variable **n** to store the number of bytes:

`n, err := bufio.NewReader(client).Read(buffer)`

and then you can take only that number of bytes from your buffer that has length of 1024:

`data := string(buffer[:n])`

**Edit:**

Other alternatives:

- you could use a json [Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) something like this: `json.NewDecoder(client).Decode(&pointer_to_struct_or_map)`
- [ioutil.ReadAll(client)](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)
- save each 1024 bytes into a [Buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) and then you can use [Bytes()](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes)

Comment: Yeap, It is the solution for my case but what if the data is bigger than 1024? I cant handle that?

Comment: nope, you'll only read the first 1024 bytes, for that I would use [ioutil.ReadAll()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) or if you can to keep that for loop you can read each 1024 bytes and write them into a [Buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) and then outside the for loop you can take the result as Bytes() or String()

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great. I will try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Yandry Pozo's answer: `n` could be more than `1024` or maybe you don't get the whole message in one call to `Read`. (Over a network that is all possible.)

So to get a reliable communication protocol you should define some message format, where the receiver can determine, wether the message is complete.

For example you could do a simple form of framing and send the length of the message in the first 4 bytes. You could then read until you get 4 bytes and then call `Read` repeatedly, until you got the whole message.

Comment: Clean and efficient answersThat was helpfull. Thanks everyone.